# Jquery doesn't load for Control Panel after move from Dev to Live

Tags: ee2, control-panel, jquery

Recently while moving from my first local dev to public site, the jquery that powers the Control Panel basically stopped working/loading. Version is v2.5.3 and I will be upgrading the dev to latest but hope to figure this out before I dive into that.

The signin screen loses all jquery and formatting (no jquery code in HTML head) and menus inside EE no longer function as well as all addons that rely on jquery. The tabs that are usually hidden for accessories such as MC Cloner and ExpressionEngine Info are showing (when they should not).

I've tried the following.

- reuploaded all theme folders and checking permissions
- Cleared Cached before and after upload
- uninstall/reinstall jquery addon
- Checked config.php for conflicting paths
- disabled extensions via config.php

Ensured the following paths are correct

- Admin ‣ General Configuration
- Admin ‣ Security and Privacy ‣ Captcha Preferences
- Admin ‣ System Administration ‣ Emoticon Preferences
- Content ‣ Files ‣ File Upload Preferences
- Members ‣ Preferences
- Design ‣ Templates ‣ Global Preferences
- Admin ‣ Channel Administration ‣ Channels

You can see the cpanel here, notice the missing jquery embed (I will change the url to admin.php before launch)
http://www.centerchurchucc.org/admin.php?S=0&D=cp&C=homepage

[image: Screenshot of Prefs]

Really puzzled on this one!

My gen prefs

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this problem? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Well aren't we snippy

Comment: It's actually an automatic comment when an answer is flagged as a non-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try to remove the trailing slash on Theme Folder Path.

By the way, you should try to keep this settings on the config.php file. It's easier to fix them on the file.

Comment: thanks but that just disabled the theme completely, the CSS failed to load.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the EXACT same issue for two weeks.  I was able to resolve it by simply overwriting the themes/javascript folder from a previous file backup to the live side via FTP.

I don't know exactly what changed when moving from dev to live originally, but thru process of elimination, I narrowed it down to this folder.