# jQuery not loading on Control Panel

Tags: control-panel, jquery

I checked [this](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10833/jquery-doesnt-load-for-control-panel-after-move-from-dev-to-live) post out and followed the things the OP posted and what other users suggested, but jQuery still isn't loading in the control panel. The themes folder is properly linked and the CSS for it has loaded just fine. It's only the jQuery that's giving me problems.

Comment: Are you receiving any JavaScript errors when you look in the Console window?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try reuploading your themes/javascript folder. This could be a symptom of a failed or incomplete upload. Also, when you open your developer console in Chrome or Firefox (hit F12), jump over to your console. What errors are you getting? Please edit your answer with this information and I can probably get you fixed up.